# The added kal library is not showing the ibrary in added linked binary with libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, kal

In my application I plan to use kal calendar . I am currently using xcode 4.6 . I installed the library by following the steps mentioned in the [link](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal/blob/master/README.markdown).

After successfully following all the mentioned steps, the added 'kal.a' file in 'linked binary with libraries' section is shown like the below image

[image]

like the above image it is shown in red color like that file has been deleted.

Help me to solve this problem

**Note**:- I added the `header search Paths` to the path of the src file

Comment: No it is not deleted! it show in this way, by the way you can not upload the the app developed in Xcode 4.6, so it would be better to use latest Xcode.

Comment: Header Search Paths needed when you don't add library from 'Linked binary with Libraries' section. If you are adding .a file as 'Add Files' then you need to specify the same.

Comment: @AsifHabib But if I import kal.h in my viewController subclass then its says 'file not found error'